# jQuery smooth mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

is there a possibility in jQuery, to make a smooth page scroll on mouse scroll?
I've arleady search the internet, but only found a solution, to smooth scroll to an anchor point, not to scroll all the page smoothly.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: what do you mean by `all the page`? why don't you create an anchor at the beginning of the page and use that plugin?

Comment: @acontell i guess op wants to change the default behaviour of mouse scrolling

Comment: yes, i think so... if you scrolling the page by mouse wheel, not by anchor points.

Comment: is this even possible?